# exec ctx_rehash fails with bash: exec: ctx_rehash: not found

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, citrix

I am in the process of Citrix Workspace on Ubuntu Mate.  I have followed the directions provided at this link:  https://jamesjmeyer210.github.io/site/blogs/installing-citrix-workspace-on-ubuntu.html

However this command specified on the page for certificate setup fails:

> $ exec ctx_reash
>
> bash: exec: ctx_rehash: not found

Running exec without any parameters completes silently, so bash definitely recognizes the command.

I have searched the internet and most of the example show redirect after "exec" and before the file specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same challenge (Mint 20.2)

In my case I just ran the ctx_hash file by going to the relevant directory and typing

```
./ctx_hash
```

that worked, "exec ctx_hash" will not work. But the file is executable so I didn't need to change permissions or anything and was able to run it fine. This resolved the problem.